# How to add to custom list view from user input?

Tags: android

Im trying to add rows to a custom list view with user input, but I dont understand how to in the customadapter class..

The custom list view layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activityName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:text="Activity Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="x:"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityName"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activityName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="y:"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/xText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/xText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/xText"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="z:"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="119dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yText"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

I've managed to find some guides that show how to enter to a custom list view from arrays, but here I want it to be added from users input..

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlistview, null);
        TextView activity_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activityName);
        TextView x_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.xText);
        TextView y_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yText);
        TextView z_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zText);

    return view;
    }

}
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18395753/1531971

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change a list or add or delete any list item, you should use an ArrayList.

Where is your ArrayList or Array where the listItems are stored? Please add every details.

*You should use RecyclerView instead of ListView. It is more configurable and dynamic.*