# How to refresh SMS Listview automatically ?

Tags: android, listview, sms, refresh

I am creating SMS app. I am sending and receiving SMS with my application and then can show them in ListView. But listview doesn't get updated as soon as I send or receive SMS. I have to press back button , after that if I again go to ListView Activity then new SMS are shown.

How can I make listview refresh automatically as soon as sms arrives or is send ?

Code is :

```
public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

private MyListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> item_id = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_time = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_flag = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
private Button btn_send;
DbManager manager;
Cursor Cursor;
ViewHolder holder12;
String contact_for_chat;
String contact_no;
String message_body = "";
Calendar c;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
String time;
EditText et_chat;
String flag;
String msg = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    contact_for_chat = bundle.getString("contact_name");
    contact_for_chat = contact_for_chat.replace(" ", "");
    contact_no = Util.getContactNumber(contact_for_chat, ChatActivity.this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contact_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    manager = new DbManager(this);
    Cursor = manager.Return_All(contact_no);
    showEvents(Cursor);

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    time = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    setActionBar();
    findViewsById();
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SendSMS();
        }
    });
}

protected void SendSMS() {
    SmsManager sms_manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    message_body = et_chat.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms_manager.divideMessage(message_body);
    sms_manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(contact_no, null, parts, null, null);
    flag = "1";
    manager.Insert_sms_data(time, contact_no, message_body,flag);
    msg+= "SMS to :" + contact_for_chat + " \n";
    msg += "having number:" + contact_no + " \n";
    msg += "as" +message_body + " \n";
    msg += "at"+ time + " \n";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void setActionBar() {
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_chat, null);
    TextView tv_chat = (TextView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    tv_chat.setText(contact_for_chat);
    ColorDrawable colorDaawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CFCFC4"));
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDaawable);
    mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}

private void findViewsById() {
    et_chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_chat);
    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
}

private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {

    item_id = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_time = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_flag = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    int i=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        item_id.add(i+"");
        item_time.add(cursor.getString(1));
        item_msg_body.add(cursor.getString(3));
        item_phone_num.add(cursor.getString(2));
        item_flag.add(cursor.getString(4));
        i++;
    }

  }
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context con;
    private LayoutInflater layoutinf;
    ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<String> items_ = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyListAdapter(ChatActivity context) {
        con = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return item_id.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null) {
            layoutinf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.row_chat, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
            holder.tv_sms_body = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if(item_flag.get(position).equals("1"))
        {
            holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);

        }
                    else 
                    {
                        holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

                    }


        holder.tv_contact.setText("" + item_phone_num.get(position));


        holder.tv_sms_body.setText(item_msg_body.get(position));

        holder.tv_time.setText(item_time.get(position));

        return v;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {

    private TextView tv_contact;
    private TextView tv_sms_body;
    private TextView tv_time;

}
}
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2250849/2591693)

Comment: what did you do? why oh why do you use custom BaseAdapter??? why not SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: After sending or receiving sms get all data from database again and bind it with listview using your custom adapter.

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but after reading through your code, I strongly recommed that you look into this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `notifydatasetchanged`. check out following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229903/2930834

Answer (score 1):

you should register a broadcast receiver to get notified upon receiving an SMS and in the onReceive of this receiver you can get new data from cursor and refresh the list view.

To know more about receiver try:

http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87