# When I upload a new photo to server my app crashes

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm doing a social application with a `listview` to show information from database. When I see the *listview* works fine but if I add a new data from the application and then I go to the `listview` again the application crashes. I think the problem is because I don't implement `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I have to do, but I don't know how can I do this.
At first I have a function to receive the photos and the information from the database and then I have a `class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter`. I think that this method must be placed inside this class:

```
 class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MyArrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return MyArrList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

Somebody knows how implement this function in my applciation?

The exception is the following:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131165257, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.xx.xx.app.Listview$ImageAdapter)]
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post the logcat with the errors of the crash?

Comment: The error shows that I need to implement this function inside ArrayAdapter (In my case ImageAdapter I think), but I don't know how it done

Comment: Right after you have added some data to your list, you should just call the notifyDataSetChanged(). Should be something like this: `YourListView.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: This should give you all the information you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12234498/3417559

Comment: I tried `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`but does not work

Comment: I've updated the post with the exception

Comment: I don't see you adding value's to your list here.. Do you have more than one thread?

Comment: Yes, all it is inside getView (Textview and Imageview)