# how to update listview with a new image selected from gallery

Tags: android, listview, onactivityresult

I have an application in which i want to update my list view with image selected from
device gallery when i clicked on the button present on the list view row. But I'm unable to show it on the list view.
what are the changes need to do to get the image on listview.
Here is my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
 ContactImageAdapter adapter;
 Bitmap bmp;
 int posi;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  // add image and text in arraylist
  imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "FaceBook"));
  imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Google"));
  imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Ical"));
  imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Outlook"));
  imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Twitter"));

  // add data in contact image adapter
  adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.fragment_main, imageArry);
  ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
 public void removeAtomPayOnClickHandler(View v) {
        Contact itemToRemove = (Contact)v.getTag();
        //adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        //adapter.insert(new AtomPayment("bbbb", 0), 0);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         posi=ContactImageAdapter.pos;
        if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            // ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
             bmp=  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
             //iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
             imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Twitter"));
             System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+ContactImageAdapter.pos+"-----"+posi);
        }


    }
}
```

and here is the code for contact.java

```
    public class Contact {

 int image;
 String name;
 public int getImage() {
  return image;
 }
 public void setImage(int image) {
  this.image = image;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public Contact(int image, String name) {
  super();
  this.image = image;
  this.name = name;
 }

}
```

and the adapter class

```
public class ContactImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
  Context context;
    public  static int pos;
     int layoutResourceId;   
      ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
     public ContactImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
         super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
         this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
         this.context = context;
         this.data = data;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View row = convertView;
         ImageHolder holder = null;
         pos=position;
         if(row == null)
         {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

             holder = new ImageHolder();
             holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
             holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
             row.setTag(holder);
         }
         else
         {
             holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
         }

         Contact myImage = data.get(position);
         holder.txtTitle.setText(myImage.name);
            int outImage=myImage.image;
         holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(outImage);
        return row;

     }

     static class ImageHolder
     {
         ImageView imgIcon;
         TextView txtTitle;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `notifyDataSetChanged`every time the list is update.  Then `notifyDataSetChanged`will work.
Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Add new image in your image array..and call notifyDataSetChanged..it will refresh your list view
Refer this link its explains all in detail [Android. How does notifyDataSetChanged() method and ListViews work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work)