# How does notifyDataSetChanged work?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I have a question on how `notifyDataSetChanged()` works in a `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

I am updating a boolean variable, the output of which determines the output of `getChildrenCount()` but the number of comments visible does not change on calling it

Code:

```
buttonViewComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                allCommentsVisible = !allCommentsVisible;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

getChildrenCount:

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if(allCommentsVisible || postList.get(groupPosition).commentListSize()<=3)
            return postList.get(groupPosition).commentListSize();
        else{
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no data change is your adapter. Please provide "allCommentsVisiable" values inside data adapter.

Comment: Currently it is a private memeber variable of "public class PostListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter"

Comment: Other memebers: private List<Post> postList;
    private Context context;
    private String SessionID;

Comment: Where should I add it/

Comment: You will get usefull information from this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work

Comment: Add "allCommentsVisiable" attribute in Post class.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged`

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
>   [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

And in your case, there isn't any underlying data changes. In order to make it work you need to change your list `postList` items so it will update the set and the counter will be updated along with the size of the set.

Answer (score 0):

You will get some useful information about this from this link.

[Android. How does notifyDataSetChanged() method and ListViews work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work)