# Use of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am very new to Android development. I am little confuse about the use of `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` with `ArrayAdapter` and `ListView`. In my project, I am displaying all student in `ListView` with the help of an `ArrayAdapter`. The `ArrayAdapter` is getting the data (`ArrayList`) from local(`Sqlite`) database. further, the local database is getting the data from server whenever the server data is changed.

I created the `adapter` instance in `onCreate()` and I bound the `Listview` with it. Whenever the local database is changed, I am trying to refresh the `ListView` with `notifyDataSetChanged()` method but somehow its not working.

Comment: Put the code :)

Comment: How are you loading the data from the database into the `ArrayAdapter`? You'll need to post the code for that at least before anyone can help you.

Comment: You should see this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work

Comment: I have come to know that Array Adapter does not responses to notifyDataSetChanged() except, adapter.add() or adapter.remove() is used. But unfortunately there is no update method of array adapter. So, in my project updation of student data is not reflecting to ListView dynamically. what should i do???