# How can I use AsyncTask, RecyclerView, and a RecyclerView.Adapter to get images from my phone into my RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load images from my phone into my recyclerview.

So far, I have created a recyclerview.adapter, and a gridlayoutmanager, and attached them to my recyclerview. I can successfully retrieve full paths of the images and add them to the adapter using an async task.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

    settingUp();
    run();

}


public void settingUp(){

    //setting up recycler view
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //setting up recyclerview layout manager
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new      GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //setting up recyclerview adapter
    adapter = getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // instance of load task
    loadTask = new LoadTask();
}

private void run() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    else
    {
        loadTask.execute();
    }
}

 /**
 * Loads the images into the cursor using a background thread
 */

private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Cursor>
{

    // images are loaded into the cursor here, in the background.
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        loadImagesIntoCursor();
        return imageCursor;
    }

    // this method runs after doInBackground finishes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        transferImagesToAdapter(cursor);
    }
}

//*********************************************************************************************************

/**
 * Loads all the Images from external storage into the cursor.
 */
private void loadImagesIntoCursor()
{
    imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
}

 private void transferImagesToAdapter(Cursor imageCursor)
{
    String path;
    if(imageCursor != null)
    {
        imageCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!imageCursor.isAfterLast()){
            path =       imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            adapter.add(path);
            imageCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        imageCursor.close();

    }

}

/** MY ADAPTER CLASS **/

class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<String> images;
//private static ImageAdapter singleton = null;
Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> paths)
{
    images = paths;
    this.context = context;
}

public ImageAdapter(Context context)
{

    this.context = context;
}



//--------- OVERRIDE METHODS ---------------------------------------------
@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout,parent);
    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    // load image into image holder view using picasso library
    Picasso.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(holder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void add(String path){
    this.images.add(path);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    protected ImageView image;
    public ImageViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        this.image = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
}
```

}

However, after adding the imagepaths I have no clue as to what trigger the onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder methods in the adapter which will display my images in the recyclerview.
Any help please!

Comment: Please post your adapter class

Comment: I've posted my adapter class @kam1234

Comment: Don't use asynctask. It is going to be deprecated from android 11.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you need to do to update RecyclerView list item.

1. Update your data list inside your adapter
2. Notify dataset change.

```
 private void transferImagesToAdapter(Cursor imageCursor)
{
    String path;
    if(imageCursor != null)
    {
        imageCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!imageCursor.isAfterLast()){
            path =       imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            adapter.add(path); // If it update data list in your adapter then fine.
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // It will do all the callbacks and update your screen.

            imageCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        imageCursor.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Putting adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() crashes the app. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

`Recycler View` and the `Recycler View Adapter` are two different things. Simply adding data to your `Adapter` will do nothing but fatten up the `Adapter` object.

The `Recycler View` has to be told that the `Adapter`'s data state has changed and that the `Recycler View` should pull the updated data from the `Adapter`.

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Calling the method [`notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) method after putting in all the data changes in the `Adapter`'s data source.
2. Using the [`DiffUtil`](https://blog.mindorks.com/the-powerful-tool-diff-util-in-recyclerview-android-tutorial)

The difference between the above mentioned techniques is that `notifyDataSetChanged` totally resets the data to the current data source's data, all of it whereas `DiffUtil` changes only the data that has been updated and doesn't bother with the ones that haven't been changed.

So, if your data source has around a 1000 objects and you change only one if them, it's better to use `DiffUtils` because `notifyDataSetChanged` will [recreate all the views even the ones that didn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work), which affects performance.

Also, the problem with [@vikas jha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58811339/6601614) is that if there are many images, there will be substantial performance bottlenecks because for even a single image addition, the entire data source will be reloaded and the fact that it's inside a loop aggravates the problem. So move the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` call outside the loop. I'm assuming that you have a `List` of images as your data source, where the add method simply adds an image to the `List`.

It's best to have an overloaded `add` method for your `adapter` which accepts a list of images, append them to the end of the existing list of images in your `adapter` (assuming that you have previously loaded images) and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

your activity class

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    run();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
    settingUp();
}


public void settingUp(){

    //setting up recycler view
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);

    //setting up recyclerview layout manager
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new      GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    // instance of load task
    loadTask = new LoadTask();
}

private void run() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
  }

 /**
 * Loads the images into the cursor using a background thread
 */

private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, List<String>
{ 

    // images are loaded into the cursor here, in the background.
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return getAllImages();
    }

    // this method runs after doInBackground finishes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String imagesList>) {
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity, magesList);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
}

//*********************************************************************************************************

/**
 * Loads all the Images from external storage into the cursor.
 */
private void getAllImages()
{
   List<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
   Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
    if(imageCursor != null)
    {
        imageCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!imageCursor.isAfterLast()){

    String path = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            imagesList.add(path);
            imageCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        imageCursor.close();

    }
    return imagesList;
}
```

Your adapter

```
/** MY ADAPTER CLASS **/

class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

private List<String> images;
Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> paths)
{
    this.images = paths;
    this.context = context;
}

//--------- OVERRIDE METHODS ---------------------------------------------
@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout,parent);
    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    // load image into image holder view using picasso library
    Picasso.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(holder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    protected ImageView image;
    public ImageViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        this.image = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
}
```